# Android OnItemClickListener value pass

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to pass a value selected in the listview, but the passed value does not match the one chosen. What's wrong? thi is my full code. I'm getting a value other than the one selected.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.detlezione, R.id.tv_nomria, dettagli){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final TextView tvId;
        final TextView tvCaa;
        ImageView tvC;
        tvC = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.color_view);
        tvId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lbl);
        tvCaa = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome_caa);
        tvCaa.setTypeface(tf);
        Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
        tvId.setText(d.id+"");
        tvCaa.setText(d.caa+"");
        tvCaa.setTextColor(d.color);
        tvC.setBackgroundColor(d.color);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Intent invia_a_movimenti = new Intent(Sce.this, Movi.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("caa", tvCaa.getText().toString());
                extras.putInt("co", tvCaa.getCurrentTextColor());
                invia_a_movimenti.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(invia_a_movimenti);
            }
        });
        return row;
    };
};
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

-----------UPDATE-------
ok, but my onResume () does not return the result, why?

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    c_scelta.setText(i.getStringExtra("caa"));
    int color;
    color = (i.getIntExtra("co", 0));
    c_scelta.setTextColor(colore_ricevuto);

     super.onResume();

}
```

Comment: what do you mean with tvC  ??

Comment: can you put the full method please?

Comment: I have included the complete code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure(since the code is not clear enough) but you should be able to do this:

```
extras.putString("caa", ((TextView)view).getText().toString());
extras.putInt("co", ((TextView)view).getCurrentTextColor());
```

Selected item is passed through the method signature of `OnItemClickListener`. So the item clicked is variable `view`. Use `view` to get information about clicked item. Besides you can use `position` or `id` variables too.

EDIT:

You shall not assign `onItemClickListener` per each of row. Instead you assign it once, so put that assignment out of `getView` method. Code below should work:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.detlezione, R.id.tv_nomria, dettagli) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tvId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lbl);
        TextView tvCaa = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome_caa);
        ImageView tvC = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.color_view);
        tvCaa.setTypeface(tf);
        Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
        tvId.setText(d.id + "");
        tvCaa.setText(d.caa + "");
        tvCaa.setTextColor(d.color);
        tvC.setBackgroundColor(d.color);
        return row;
    };
};
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent invia_a_movimenti = new Intent(Sce.this, Movi.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        TextView tvCaa = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome_caa);
        extras.putString("caa", tvCaa.getText().toString());
        extras.putInt("co", tvCaa.getCurrentTextColor());
        invia_a_movimenti.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(invia_a_movimenti);
    }
});
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Still I am suggesting you to use `ViewHolder`. Google it and learn it well.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get your idea. You try to access the selected textview in Listview and get its attributes, then on the onSelecteditem method when callback, it give you some parameters like the selected view in list that contain the textview and the position of the selected view and the id of it what you need now is to get the textview in selected item so you need

```
TextView selectedTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewId);
extras.putString("caa",selectdTextView.getText().toString());
```

and now you can access any data from your textview